# Error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' for argument '1' to 'int upper(char**)'

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I have an assignment to calculate the number of vowels,capital letters, consonants etc. in an array. But I keep getting the
error:

> Error cannot convert 'char*' to 'char** ' for argument '1' to
>   'int upper(char**)'

I have no idea why I get this error.

My main program:

```
#include "stringCount.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int SIZE = 1024;  // The maximum size of the C-string
    char cstring[SIZE];     
    char choice;        

    cout << "Enter a C-string of at most 1024 characters: ";
    cin.getline(cstring, SIZE); //Get a c-string

    // Display the Menu

   do
   {
      cout << "\tA) Count the number of vowels in the string\n";
      cout << "\tB) Count the number of consonants in the string\n";
      cout << "\tC) Count the number of uppercase alphabets in the string\n";
      cout << "\tD) Count the number of lowercase alphabets in the string\n";
      cout << "\tE) Count the number of alphabets in the string\n";
      cout << "\tF) Count the number of digits in the string\n";
      cout << "\tG) Find the average number character in each word of the string\n";
      cout << "\tH) Display the string with first letter of words capitalized\n";
      cout << "\tI) Enter a new string string\n";
      cout << "\tQ) Quit this program\n\n";

      cout << "\tEnter your choice (A - I) or Q: ";
      cin >> choice;

      while ((toupper(choice) < 'A' || toupper(choice) > 'I') && toupper(choice)!='Q')
      {
         cout << "\tEnter ONLY (A - I) or Q: ";
         cin >> choice;
      }

        // Process User's choice
      switch (toupper(choice))
      {
         case 'A':   cout << "The string has " << vowel(cstring) << " vowels." << endl;
                     break;
         case 'B':   cout << "The string has " << consonant(cstring) << " consonants." << endl;
                     break;
        case 'C':   cout << "There are " << upper(cstring) << " uppercase alphabets in the string." << endl;
                     break;
        case 'D':   cout << "There are " << lower(cstring) << " lowercase alphabets in the string." << endl;
                     break;
        case 'E':   cout << "There are " << alphabet(cstring) << " alphabets in the string." << endl;
                     break;
        case 'F':   cout << "There are " << digit(cstring) << " digits in the string." << endl;
                     break;
            case 'G':   cout << "There average number of letters per word in the string is " << wordCount(cstring) << "." << endl;
                     break;
            case 'H':   cout << "The capitalized string is: "  << endl;
                            capital(cstring);
                            cout << cstring << endl;
                     break;                     
         case 'I':   cin.get();
                     cout << "Enter a C-string of at most 1024 characters: ";
                     cin.getline(cstring, SIZE);
                     break; 
            case 'Q':       cout << "Goodbye!\n";
                     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
      }
   } while (toupper(choice) != 'Q');

    return 0;}
```

My header file:

```
    #ifndef STRING_COUNT
    #define STRING_COUNT

    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    double wordCount(char *[]);
    void capital(char *[]);
    int vowel(char *[]);
    int consonant(char *[]);
    int upper(char *[]);
    int lower(char *[]);
    int alphabet(char *[]);
    int digit(char *[]);

    #endif
```

My implementation file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "stringCount.h"

double wordCount(char*words)
{
    int a, size, word=0 ;

    size = sizeof (words);

    for (a=0 ; a < size ; a++)
    {
         if (isspace(words[a]))
         {
            word++;
         }
    }
    return word+1;
}
//======================================================================
void capital(char * words)
{
    int i,  size ;

    size = sizeof (words);


    for (i=0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        if (isspace(words[i])&& isalpha(words[i+1]) )
        {
            words[i+1] = toupper(words[i+1]);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
//=====================================================================
int vowel(char * words)
{
    int a =0;
    int size, vowels=0 ;
    size =  sizeof(words);   

    for (a=0; a< size;  a++)

    {
        if( words[a]== 'a'|| words[a] == 'e' || words[a]== 'i' || words[a] == 'o' || words[a] == 'u' ||words[a]== 'A'|| words[a] == 'E' || words[a]== 'I' || words[a] == 'O' || words[a] == 'U')
        {
            vowels++;
        } 
    }
    return vowels;
}
//=====================================================================
int consonant(char * words)
{
    int i,  size,  cons =0;  
    size = sizeof(words);

      for (i = 0; i< size ; i++)
      {
        if (isalpha(words[i])&!( words[i]== 'a'|| words[i] == 'e' || words[i]== 'i' || words[i] == 'o' || words[i] == 'u' ||words[i]== 'A'|| words[i] == 'E' || words[i]== 'I' || words[i] == 'O' || words[i] == 'U'))
        {
            cons++ ;
        }

      } ;


     return cons; 
}
//====================================================================
int upper(char * words)
{

     int i,  size,  uppercase =0 ;

     size = sizeof(words);
     for (i = 0 ; i< size ; i++)
     {
        if (isupper(words[i]))
        {
            uppercase++;
        }
     }

     return uppercase;

}
//===============================================================
int lower(char * words)
{

     int i,  size,  lowercase =0 ;

     size = sizeof(words);
     for (i = 0 ; i< size ; i++)
     {
        if (islower(words[i]))
        {
            lowercase++;
        }
     }

     return lowercase;

}
//================================================================
int alphabet(char * words)
{
    int alphab =0;

    int i,  size;    
    size = sizeof(words);

      for (i = 0; i< size ; i++)
      {
        if (isalpha(words[i]))
        {
            alphab++ ;
        }

      }
    return alphab;
}
//=================================================================
int digit(char * words)
{
    int a,  size,  digi =0;
    size = sizeof(words);

    for (a=0 ; a < size ; a++)
    {
        if(isdigit(words[a]))
        {
            digi ++;
        }
    }
    return digi ;   
}
//=====================================================================
```

Comment: Please reduce the amount of code to a **minimal** example that reproduces your issue. Shouldn't be more than ~10 lines in this case. Also please explain what exactly you don't understand from the error message.

Comment: `double wordCount(char*words)` has a different signature as it was declared:`double wordCount(char *[]);`

Comment: People here like to help, yes, but you can't just put your whole program on here and say "please tell my why it's not working". Can you please at least give the line number which causes the error? And also try to construct a minimal example using that one line. What you're doing now is just disrespectful to the community, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Change function declaration

```
int upper(char *[]);
```

to

```
int upper(char *);
```

Or even to

```
int upper( const char * );
```

Take into account that the function definition is also wrong

Instead of

```
 size = sizeof(words);
```

you have to use

```
 size = strlen(words);
```

The same is valid for other function definitions.

The function could be defined the following way

```
int upper( const char * words )
{
    int uppercase = 0 ;

    for ( const char *p = words; *p != '\0'; ++p )
    {
        if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++uppercase;
    }

    return uppercase;
}
```

Comment: If changing to `int upper(const char * words) {` the prototypes will also need to be updated to include `const`

Comment: thanks a bunch , you have no idea how much this mean to me , I've been pulling my hair out , out of frustration , for the past week over this .