# Passing array of strings as function argument

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I have a function `cost` which does several calculations with arrays of floats and arrays of strings:

```
const int numofparticles = 20;
const int numofdims = 46;
const int numforn = 222;
const int forn_sem_repet = 92;
const int ct = 102;

using namespace std; 
 float cost(float x[numofdims], float M[numofdims][numforn], char prod[numofdims][ct], char forn_list[numforn][ct], float qtde[numofdims][1], float min_prices[forn_sem_repet][1], char min_forn[forn_sem_repet][ct]){
    float v = 0;
// does stuff
// ...
    return v
```

In the function main, the variables are loaded from files:

```
int main(){
    std::ifstream in("M.txt");
    std::string line;

    float M[numofdims][numforn];
    int i = 0, k = 0;

    while (std::getline(in, line))
    {
        float value;
        int k = 0;
        std::stringstream ss(line);

        while (ss >> value)
        {
            M[i][k] = value;
            ++k;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    i=0;

    char* prod[numofdims];
    char linee[102];

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("prod.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(linee, sizeof linee, file)!=NULL) {

        prod[i]=strdup(linee); 
        i++;
    }


    unsigned int number_of_lines = 0;
    FILE *infile = fopen("forn_list.txt", "r");
    int ch;

    while (EOF != (ch=getc(infile)))
        if ('\n' == ch)
            ++number_of_lines;


    int j=0;
    int num=0;
    char* forn_list[number_of_lines];
    char line_forn[102];

    FILE *file_forn;
    file_forn = fopen("forn_list.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line_forn, sizeof line_forn, file_forn)!=NULL) {
        forn_list[j]=strdup(line_forn); 

        j++;

    }



    std::ifstream inn("qtde.txt");
    std::string line3;

    float qtde[numofdims][1];
    int ii = 0, kk = 0;

    while (std::getline(inn, line3))
    {
        float value;
        int kk = 0;
        std::stringstream ss(line3);

        while (ss >> value)
        {
            qtde[ii][kk] = value;
            ++kk;
        }
        ++ii;
    }
    for(i=0;i<46;i++){
        for(j=0;j<1;j++){
        }

    }

    std::ifstream in_min_prices("min_prices.txt");
    std::string line_min_prices;

    float min_prices[forn_sem_repet][1];
    int iii = 0, kkk = 0;

    while (std::getline(in_min_prices, line_min_prices))
    {
        float value_min_prices;
        int kkk = 0;
        std::stringstream ss(line_min_prices);

        while (ss >> value_min_prices)
        {
            min_prices[iii][kkk] = value_min_prices;
            ++kkk;
        }
        ++iii;
    }

    j=0;
    char *min_forn[forn_sem_repet];
    char line_min_forn[102];

    FILE *file_min_forn;
    file_min_forn = fopen("min_forn.txt", "r");

    while(fgets(line_min_forn, sizeof line_min_forn, file_min_forn)!=NULL) {

        min_forn[j]=strdup(line_min_forn); 

        j++;
    }

     float x[46] = {  1.45733801,   5.4023114 ,   9.84244649,  15.63424831,
        18.54989641,  25.31747823,  31.02406554,  33.49572919,
        42.62398295,  48.89093797,  54.92222913,  64.81761377,
        67.91368849,  75.25842566,  80.76891534,  84.16383935,
        86.98898142,  92.46614131,  95.171554  ,  98.5018263 ,
       100.66458007, 106.27617827, 113.53476385, 120.35501434,
       124.50124045, 126.93877296, 133.38186583, 139.5347655 ,
       149.73161149, 155.68895627, 158.55511946, 165.81101556,
       172.92551422, 176.92861446, 181.29821916, 182.56432251,
       185.22709498, 187.98060952, 191.70461679, 193.87301843,
       198.86751373, 203.25597481, 210.26505926, 216.52723747,
       219.20956646, 220.61524748};

       float v = cost( x, M, prod,forn_list, qtde, min_prices, min_forn);

}
```

Then, in the main function, after loading all variables, I call the function cost:

```
float v = cost( x, M, prod,forn_list, qtde, min_prices, min_forn);
```

Then I get the following error:

> error: cannot convert ‘char**’ to ‘char (*)[102]’ for argument ...

And the arguments giving errors are all the char ones. These variables are of course arrays of strings. I tried to fix this passing the pointer:

```
float cost(float x[numofdims], float M[numofdims][numforn], char *prod[numofdims], char *forn_list[numforn], float qtde[numofdims][1], float min_prices[forn_sem_repet][1], char *min_forn[forn_sem_repet])
```

But then I get

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I would like to know why this happened and how to fix it.

Comment: I think you need to share ur prod and forn_list functions. I see u tried the method mentioned in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411706/error-cannot-convert-char-to-char-for-argument-1-to-int-upperchar But it may not about calling functions maybe cos of declaration

Comment: Please show us how you call `cost` and how you initialize the arrays you pass to it. But I guess the best answer is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of pointers or c-style arrays.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question with the function main. The variables are loaded from txt files, and since I am just testing the function cost, I used basically the same code to load all of them.  I already checked these variables, and they are all what I expected.

Comment: I think the problem is a mismatching of the dimensions of the arrays. The error says that you can't convert an array of string in a matrix with columns=102. Try to use strings.

Comment: "char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream )" This is the format of "fgets". Your "linee" array doesnt match with this format. You should change ur declaration according to this format.

Comment: After fixing the types, you are probably writing outside the bounds of some of those one-element arrays. Use `std::vector` and `std::string`.

Comment: As an aside, you should consider putting related parameters into a struct/class and passing an array (or even better, vector) of those instead of multiple independent arrays of same length.

Answer (score 0):

char prod[numofdims][ct] - is type with strong size: all strings into prod are 102 char size (the real strings can be less with zero char, but you allocate 102 char for each string). And this type can't be casted to char** (this type is array of pointers to char array) - these are different types.

It's better to use vector of string. Or you can make an array of chars with 102 * n size and fill it "by hand".